# SQL Update query with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Is it better that I just use the where for update query with conditions or there is a better way to do?

Below is a sample of my SQL query which I wanted to update if the `Order_ID = 10` plus `payment_check is N` or `response_msg is null`, kindly correct me if my query is wrong.

```
UPDATE dbo.sample1
    SET Payment_Generated = 'Y',
    Transaction_ID = '123',
    Response_Msg = 'ok',
    Response_Code = '1',
    Created_on = '2020-05-29T11:29:30'
WHERE Order_ID = '10' and Payment_Check = 'N' or Response_Code IS NULL
```

Expected Result if the payment_check is N or response_code is null

```
Payment_Generated = 'Y',
Transaction_ID = '123',
Response_Msg = 'ok',
Response_Code = '1',
Created_on = '2020-05-29T11:29:30'
Order_ID = '10'
Payment_Check = 'N'
```

Comment: Your question is unclear... I recommend showing some sample data and expected results. And are you missing a single quote after `ok`?

Comment: Or in T-SQL is written ` OR ` so maybe changing `/` to `OR` is all you need to do to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, sorry for the question unclear, I have edited the question. My question is this the usual way to perform an update query with conditions or is there another way to update the DB with certain conditions?

Comment: Thats the *only* way to update a record in SQL Server? What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I see, thanks for the confirmation. On a side note, I assume this update query won't be executed if order_id is not 10 plus payment_check = 'Y' or response_code is not null right?

Comment: No - T-SQL does respect the where clause - its not optional :)

Comment: When combining `AND` and `OR` its advisable to always use parentheses. Do you mean `(Order_ID = '10' and Payment_Check = 'N') or Response_Code IS NULL` or `Order_ID = '10' and (Payment_Check = 'N' or Response_Code IS NULL)`?